# Obtaining CSV from a static file using tags to avoid cross-domain policy

Tags: javascript, html, csv, cross-domain-policy

I'm programming a C++ application which generates the report data in Javascript instead of CSV. I advocate that HTML and Javascript provides a powerful tool to generate and show reports. But generates the Javascript code in C++ it's a bit clunky.

I'm attempting to read a CSV from Javascript but I realise that it isn't possible owing to the cross-domain policy. I'd like to facilitate the client to see the report without obliging to disable the cross-domain security.

**Code that works:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Read CSV from static file - Avoiding cross origin</title>
    <script id="data" type="text/csv">
    x, y
    0, 0
    1, 1
    2, 4 
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var data = document.getElementById('data');
      alert(data.innerHTML);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Code that does not work:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Read CSV from static file - Avoiding cross origin</title>
    <script id="data" type="text/csv" src="data.csv"></script>
  </head>

  <body>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var data = document.getElementById('data');
      alert(data.text);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why using only an external plain text data does not show me anything? Can I solve this using `<link>` or `<meta>` tags? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi. I would not recommend CSV, basically because it's old and limited tecnology. I would recommend JSON.